# Can't Install libcurl PHP on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, apache2, libcurl

I am trying to use the new facebook api and it requires libcurl PHP.  I used

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

And it didn't work.  I get the same error and the phpinfo() page says nothing about libcurl.

The source of this problem is probably that I built some of the tools from source (apache2, php), but then I got bored so installed a lot of the extensions with the package manager.  But I'm not exactly how to go about diagnosing the point of failure.

The apt-get install for curl definitely worked, and can be found in

/usr/lib/php5/20060613/curl.so

I think a lot of my confusion stems from not knowing which files go where, and what purpose they have.  Any help would be appreciated, and please tell me if I need to provide more information.

**edit:**
The specific error I get is:

```
Exception: Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.
```

from line

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
  throw new Exception('Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.');
}
```

Ubuntu: 9.10

PHP: 5.2.13

Loaded Configuration File: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: What "same error" do yo mean? What error message do you get?

Comment: Should be asked on: superuser.com

Comment: Well it can be migrated there if people feel it absolutely belongs there, but it is obviously programming related so I could see it on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it's a bad idea to mix and match software from your distribution's package manager with stuff you've built yourself. The package manager will *not* know anything about the stuff you've built yourself and so can get confused.

Not only that but who's to say the stuff from the package manager is even binary compatible with the stuff you've built yourself? If you build it all yourself then at least you know it will all be compatible.

Sounds to me like you should uninstall the extensions and build them yourself. If you can't or don't want to do that then go back and install apache and friends through your package manager but I would recommend having patience and going for the former option.

Comment: This is what I figured, and what my eventual recourse will be.  I was hoping for a shortcut if it was just a configuration problem :)

Comment: @FranticPedantic: Probably a good idea. Don't get me wrong though, it may well be just a configuration problem in this case (which others will be better qualified to diagnose than me for sure) but I think you're better off with everything built the same way and then you know what you are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

Answer of Questions

What version of Ubuntu?

What version of PHP?

How is Apache and PHP set up?

What ini files does phpinfo() say is parsed? (should be near the top)

Comment: some of these questions are better made as comments, as they don't really add any answers to the question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps apt failed to properly modify your php.ini file to load the curl extension?

Check out your php.ini and see if you have line like:

```
extension=curl.so
```

or maybe:

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20060613/curl.so
```

Comment: the package creates the following ini file: /etc/php5/conf.d/curl.ini
which just includes the line:
extension=curl.so

Answer (score 1):

### To check if php-curl is installed please follow these steps:

1. Create a file in your web server (in Ubuntu it would be in /var/www folder), name it info.php
2. Open that file and type this command:

   ```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```
3. Save that file
4. Open your favorite browser and open that file (ex: `http://localhost/info.php`)
5. Now you will see the Information about your PHP installation
6. Search for Curl, and if you cannot find it, it mean your php doesn’t have curl installed.

---

### To install php-curl please follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal and type this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-mcrypt
   ```
2. After it finish open php.ini file (mine is at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini ) and add this command: extension=curl.so
3. Save the file and restart apache with this command:

   ```
   /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```
4. Check the PHP information page again, you will find PHP-CURL installed
5. That’s it

---

Source: http://www.ivankristianto.com/os/ubuntu/howto-install-curl-in-php-apache/379/

Comment: This is a good start, but would probably get more interest as a response if it had the numbered items on separate lines, and if #2 had the code written into it such that it was visible (you can do this using the '{}' button above the answer edit box.)

Comment: IT WORKED FOR ME `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-mcrypt` AND RESTART.. THANKS :d